# Why do the subviews of a subview not appear no matter what constraints are input?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a view controller and inside its view I added a `UIView`. Inside of that I'm trying to add subviews to it, such as a uipickerview and a segment control.

The issue is that no matter what constraints I add, they don't appear if I put `headerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` to the view that will contain them. Here are my constraints for all the views.

```swift
view.addSubview(tableView)
           
//Setting up the HeaderView
var headerView = UIView()
self.view.addSubview(headerView)
headerView.backgroundColor = .systemRed
headerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
headerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
headerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
headerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
headerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive=true
            
//Setting up the list picker
var listPicker = CustomHorizontalPickerView()
headerView.addSubview(listPicker)
listPicker.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
listPicker.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
listPicker.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
listPicker.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: headerView.frame.height / 2 ).isActive = true
setTableViewDelegates()
tableView.rowHeight = 50
tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
   
self.tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomCellNSB2", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCellNSB2")
```

My list picker won't appear unless I delete `translatesAutoresizing`, and then it appears in the wrong place. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
 listPicker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

and change

```
listPicker.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: headerView.frame.height / 2 ).isActive = true
```

to

```
listPicker.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:25).isActive = true
```